# How to lookup and inject a foreign object by id with Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I've got some collections of objects with basic 1-to-many relations between them. My goal is to write a function (or functions that can be composed if necessary) in order to resolve / inject foreign ID fields to foreign objects.

For instance, I've got the following object:

```
const store = {
  users: [
    {
      teamId: 'team-1',
      name: 'user 1',
    },
    {
      teamId: 'team-2',
      name: 'user 2',
    },
  ],
  teams: [
    {
      id: 'team-1',
      regionId: 'region-1',
      name: 'Team 1',
    },
    {
      id: 'team-2',
      regionId: 'region-2',
      name: 'Team 2',
    }
  ],
  regions: [
    {
      id: 'region-1',
      name: 'Region 1',
    },
    {
      id: 'region-2',
      name: 'Region 2',
    },
  ],
}
```

My goal is to resolve it to the following:

```
const users = [
    {
      teamId: 'team-1',
      name: 'user 1',
      team: {
        id: 'team-1',
        regionId: 'region-1',
        region: {
          id: 'region-1',
          name: 'Region 1',
        },
        name: 'Team 1',
      }
    },
    // ...and so on
]
```

I'm not far from having resolved the first level:

```
const findObject = (collection, idField = 'id') => id => R.find(R.propEq(idField, id), R.prop(collection, store))
const findTeam = findObject('teams')
const findRegion = findObject('regions')
const inject = field => R.useWith(
  R.merge,
  [R.objOf(field), R.identity]
)
const injectTeam = R.useWith(
  inject('team'),
  [findTeam]
)
const injectRegion = R.useWith(
  inject('region'),
  [findRegion]
)

R.map(injectTeam('team-1'))(store.users)
```

But this is just too much for me to get my head around this, I have only done much simpler things with Ramda so far.
The solution ideally would allow me to compose the injector functions somehow, thus resolving deeper levels would be optional.

Comment: [folktale/maybe](https://folktale.origamitower.com/docs/v2.3.0/migrating/from-data.maybe) would be a good start, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda was written in the ES5 days, and needed to support ES3.  Since the introduction of ES6, there are many things that Ramda really improved for old JS that are now simply easier in vanilla JS.  Note that I'm a Ramda founder and a big fan, but destructuring, arrow functions, default parameters, template strings, and many other things make it so that it's often cleaner to skip Ramda.

Here's a plain JS solution:

```js
const denormalize = (steps) => (store) => 
  steps.reduce(
    (s, [key, foreignKey, target, targetId, newKey]) => ({
      ...s, 
      [key]: s[key].map(({[foreignKey]: fk, ...rest}) => ({
        ...rest,
        [newKey]: s[target].find(x => x[targetId] == fk)
      }))
    })
    , store
  )

const updateStore = denormalize([
  ['teams', 'regionId', 'regions', 'id', 'region'],
  ['users', 'teamId', 'teams', 'id', 'team'],
])

const store = {users: [{teamId: "team-1", name: "user 1"}, {teamId: "team-2", name: "user 2"}], teams: [{id: "team-1", regionId: "region-1", name: "Team 1"}, {id: "team-2", regionId: "region-2", name: "Team 2"}], regions: [{id: "region-1", name: "Region 1"}, {id: "region-2", name: "Region 2"}]}

console.log(updateStore(store).users)
```

Note that this does all the denormalization, returning an object with all the denormalized data included.  We just extract `users` from it.  Obviously, we could add one more wrapper to return only that part we want, but it seems that this would likely still be useful.  (So you could get the denormalized `teams` property if you like.)

This goes one step further than your request, omitting the foreign keys and replacing them with the foreign object.  It was simply based on a misunderstanding of what you wanted, or perhaps thinking that this is what I'd want ( ;-) ).  So the results look like:

```js
[
  {
    name: "user 1",
    team: {
      id: "team-1",
      name: "Team 1",
      region: {
        id: "region-1",
        name: "Region 1"
      }
    }
  }, /*... */
]
```

If you want to keep those foreign keys, the code is a bit simpler:

```js
const denormalize = (steps) => (store) => 
  steps.reduce(
    (s, [key, foreignKey, target, targetId, newKey]) => ({
      ...s, 
      [key]: s[key].map(t => ({
        ...t,
        [newKey]: s[target].find(x => x[targetId] == t[foreignKey])
      }))
    })
    , store
  )
```

What all those strings mean in the `steps` parameter might be obscure.  If so you  could replace it with this:

```js
const config = [
  {key: 'teams', foreignKey: 'regionId', target: 'regions', targetId: 'id', newKey: 'region'},
  {key: 'users', foreignKey: 'teamId', target: 'teams', targetId: 'id', newKey: 'team'},
]
```

and simply change the first line of the `reduce` to

```js
    (s, {key, foreignKey, target, targetId, newKey}) => ({
```

(This is just a change from `[ ... ]` to `{ ... }`.)

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer (again). I have also ended up realising vanilla JS would be better here instead of sticking to pure Ramda. Anyway, it was a good practice again finding ways to this problem - thanks for the other answers too - user633183 & Ori Drori.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way you could do it using [folktale/maybe](https://folktale.origamitower.com/docs/v2.3.0/migrating/from-data.maybe). I'm going to start with the high-level function `makeUser`, then work our way backwards from there -

```
const makeUser = (user = {}) =>
  injectTeam (user)
    .chain
      ( u =>
          injectRegion (u.team)
            .map
              ( t =>
                  ({ ...u, team: t })
              )
      )
    .getOrElse (user)
```

Each `injector` takes a `get` function, a `set` function, and `store` -

```
const injectTeam =
  injector
    ( o => o.teamId
    , o => team => ({ ...o, team })
    , store.teams
    )

const injectRegion =
  injector
    ( o => o.regionId
    , o => region => ({ ...o, region })
    , store.regions
    )
```

The generic `injector` attempts to `find` using `get` then `set` -

```
const injector = (get, set, store = []) => (o = {}) =>
  find (get (o), store) .map (set (o))
```

Now we implement `find` so that it returns a *Maybe* -

```
const { Just, Nothing } =
  require ("folktale/maybe")

const fromNullable = v =>
  v == null
    ? Nothing ()
    : Just (v)

const find = (id = "", vs = []) =>
  fromNullable (vs .find (v => v.id === id))
```

Putting it all together, now we just call `makeUser` for each item in your `store.users` -

```
store.users .map (makeUser)
```

Output

```
[ { teamId: "team-1"
  , name: "user 1"
  , team: { id: "team-1"
          , regionId: "region-1"
          , name: "Team 1"
          , region: { id: "region-1"
                    , name: "Region 1"
                    }
          }
  }
, { teamId: "team-2"
  , name: "user 2"
  , team: { id: "team-2"
          , regionId: "region-2"
          , name: "Team 2"
          , region: { id: "region-2"
                    , name: "Region 2"
                    }
          }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using R.converge to extract the `users` and create the lookup of `teams` and `regions`, and then map the `users` by replacing `teamId` with the team from the lookup, and internally doing the same for the region.

```js
const { pipe, pick, map, indexBy, prop, converge, assoc, identity, flip, evolve } = R

// create a lookup of id -> object from teams and regions
const createLookup = pipe(
  pick(['teams', 'regions']),
  map(indexBy(prop('id')))
)

// add the value from the idPath in the lookup to the resultPath of the current object 
const injectFromLookup = (idKey, lookup, resultKey) => 
  converge(assoc(resultKey), [
    pipe(
      prop(idKey),
      flip(prop)(lookup),
    ),
    identity,
  ])

// extract users, create lookup, and map users to the required form
const inject = converge(
  (users, lookup) => map(
    pipe(
      injectFromLookup('teamId', prop('teams', lookup), 'team'),
      evolve({
        team: injectFromLookup('regionId', prop('regions', lookup), 'region')
      })
    )
  , users),
  [prop('users'), createLookup],
)

const store = {"users":[{"teamId":"team-1","name":"user 1"},{"teamId":"team-2","name":"user 2"}],"teams":[{"id":"team-1","regionId":"region-1","name":"Team 1"},{"id":"team-2","regionId":"region-2","name":"Team 2"}],"regions":[{"id":"region-1","name":"Region 1"},{"id":"region-2","name":"Region 2"}]}

console.log(inject(store))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```